# C# parsing string/innerhtml to get specific data

Tags: c#, selenium, innerhtml

Okay I'm trying to extract specific data from `img src` tags inside the `innerhtml`,

Example of code to get `innerhtml`:

```
var list = driver.FindElement(By.Id("list"));
var innerHtml = list.GetAttribute("innerHTML");

Console.Write(innerHtml);
```

which then outputs

```
<list class="bla">
    <img src="http://www.example.com?id=1&number=1">
    <img src="http://www.example.com?id=12&number=11">
    <img src="http://www.example.com?id=13&number=111">
    <img src="http://www.example.com?id=11&number=11">
    <img src="http://www.example.com?id=21&number=12">
</list>
```

but what I want to output is the id value & the number value,

```
1,1
12,11
13,111
11,11
21,12
```

how can I correctly get the value from

```
id=
```

&

```
number=
```

Comment: Use Html Agility Pack http://html-agility-pack.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RegularExpression` as follow to get desired result:

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(innerHtml, @"id=(?<id>\d+)&number=(?<number>\d+)"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["id"] + "," + m.Groups["number"]);
}
```